# Animate a list using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, css-transitions, ng-animate

I am building an Angularjs app. I have an Array of strings available on the scope:

```
$scope.messages = ["message1", "message2", "message3"];  
$scope.currentMessage = $scope.messages[0];
```

I have on `index.html`  a div with that variable:

```
<div>{{currentMessage}}</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how to have `$scope.currentMessage` loop through `$scope.messages` and have the div do an animation with that value showing (e.g. have it float across the screen). Then when the animation is done, I would like to repeat that process but for the next value in the array.

It is a lot of new concepts for me, perhaps it is very trivial. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds just what a normal slider would do. I would go about that creating all the elements that need to be slid in the `div` (ex. ul filled with li's) in the order they need to appear. Now write a function to slide them one after the other (negative maring-left works great for me)

Comment: @nassan :check this --> http://plnkr.co/edit/JeY8KOJMuq5mzZTbnhnL?p=preview